# List categories with number count for each item

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i want to list on category page, 6 categories with count of items for each.

My table is..

**table: categorii**

```
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+
| catid  |  name  |  title |  url     |  icon  |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+
|   1    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 1.jpg  |
|   2    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 2.jpg  |
|   3    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 3.jpg  |
|   4    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 4.jpg  |
|   5    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 5.jpg  |
|   6    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 6.jpg  |
|   7    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 7.jpg  |
|   8    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 8.jpg  |
|   9    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 9.jpg  |
|   10   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 10.jpg |
|   11   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 11.jpg |
|   12   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 12.jpg |
|   13   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 13.jpg |
|   14   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 14.jpg |
|   15   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 15.jpg |
|   16   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 16.jpg |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+
```

**table: jocuri**

```
+---------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| fileid  |  name  | category | category2 | category3 | category4 | category5 | category6 |   status  +
+---------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    1    |  name  |     1    |    9      |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |      1    |
|    2    |  name  |     1    |    18     |     24    |     16    |     11    |     9     |      0    |
|    3    |  name  |     2    |    11     |     9     |     13    |     0     |     0     |      0    |
|    4    |  name  |     1    |    20     |     14    |     0     |     0     |     0     |      1    |
|    5    |  name  |     6    |    8      |     16    |     22    |     10    |     18    |      1    |
|    6    |  name  |     2    |    13     |     10    |     0     |     0     |     0     |      1    |
|    7    |  name  |     1    |    14     |     9     |     8     |     0     |     0     |      0    |
|    8    |  name  |     5    |    12     |     11    |     9     |     15    |     8     |      1    |
|    9    |  name  |     1    |    9      |     8     |     11    |     13    |     10    |      1    |
|    10   |  name  |     1    |    10     |     8     |     9     |     0     |     0     |      1    |
|    11   |  name  |     1    |    8      |     9     |     12    |     10    |     16    |      1    |
|    12   |  name  |     6    |    10     |     0     |     0     |     0     |     0     |      0    |
+---------|--------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

what is the right command(php and mysql) to list on categories page, all categories with status 1, random and to show number of fileid on each categories?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**. Please read [*How to Ask*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far?

Comment: what does that table jocuri really do? what is it for? is the table categorii linked with jocuri? if yes... by which of all the categories field...?

Comment: on table jocuri is listed items and on the rows category, category2, etc. is the categories from table categorii

Comment: As I understand it you have files in jocury, which each have 6 categories?
In that case I'd change your database to have an extra table linking categories to files. Also, what do you mean with 'status 1'?

Comment: status 1 is primary category, status 0 is secondary category

Comment: Every jocuri row is list of 6 categories, linked to categorii table, I got that. @TerryO.: do something for yourself, make a third table with columns: jocuri_fileid, categorii_catid, and fill it with coresponding values from columns categoryX. So for fileid 1 you will get rows [(1,1), (1,9)] in new table. After that, remove columns categoryX and try to code what you are asking for (it gonna get a lot of easier), if you fail, post your code here after.

Answer (score 1):

Start with changing your database to 3 tables.

Categories

```
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+
| catid  |  name  |  title |  url     |  icon  |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+
|   1    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 1.jpg  |
|   2    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 2.jpg  |
|   3    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 3.jpg  |
|   4    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 4.jpg  |
|   5    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 5.jpg  |
|   6    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 6.jpg  |
|   7    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 7.jpg  |
|   8    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 8.jpg  |
|   9    |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 9.jpg  |
|   10   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 10.jpg |
|   11   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 11.jpg |
|   12   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 12.jpg |
|   13   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 13.jpg |
|   14   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 14.jpg |
|   15   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 15.jpg |
|   16   |  Name  |  Name  |  urlname | 16.jpg |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+
```

FileIDs

```
+---------+--------+
| fileid  |  name  |
+---------+--------+
|    1    |  name  |
|    2    |  name  |
|    3    |  name  |
|    4    |  name  |
|    5    |  name  |
|    6    |  name  |
|    7    |  name  |
|    8    |  name  |
|    9    |  name  |
|    10   |  name  |
|    11   |  name  |
|    12   |  name  |
+---------|--------+
```

FileIDs_has_Categories

```
    +---------+------------+
    | fileid  |  category  |
    +---------+------------+
    |    1    |    1       |
    |    1    |    9       |
    |    2    |    1       |
    |    2    |    18      |
    |    2    |    24      |
    |    2    |    16      |
    |    2    |    11      |
    |    2    |    9       |
    |    3    |    11      |
    |    3    |    9       |
    |    3    |    13      |
    |    4    |    1       |
    +---------|------------+
```

Then you could get the count of your categories (the number of file-id's linked to that category) by

```
SELECT COUNT(fileid) FROM FileIDs_has_Categories where category = 1
```

Which would return how much files you have with category 1

Comment: this is a correct approach, mentioned in question's comments as well: +1

Comment: Indeed, but since topicstarter seems to be a beginner, I decided to write it out a bit more in detail.